# How to animate elements moving to another spot in DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

Using jquery, css3, I want to move a div tag to another spot but not instantly, I want to animate it.

Suppose I have this

```
<div>
    <div class='item' style='float:left;'>1</div>
    <div class='item' style='float:left;'>2</div>
    <div class='item' style='float:left;'>3</div>
</div>
```

I want to move the first div item (the one that has innertext `1`) to the bottom, so it looks like this

```
<div>
    <div class='item' style='float:left;'>2</div>
    <div class='item' style='float:left;'>3</div>
    <div class='item' style='float:left;'>1</div>
</div>
```

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: what have you tried? i don't think SO is the place where you ask for something and people write the code for you.. ~

Comment: i'd have liked answer for this, if questions can't be answered in 30 secs...everyone is butthurt then..

Comment: Also, there's all kinds of animation out there, the question sounds too abstract.. I think you should describe the desired animation more specificly.

Answer (score 1):

When moving the element would cause a reflow of elements, you have to put dummy elements to hold the dimensions of the source and destination. In your case, you could clone the first item, set the clone to `visiblility: hidden`, then clone the clone and append it after the 3rd element. Then make the first item `position: absolute` and animate its left and top values from the position of the 1st dummy to the position of the 2nd dummy. When the animation completes, append the animated element, remove its inline styles, and delete the dummies. For an example of a real library that does similar, see jQuery Draggable/Droppable.